# Beginners guide to troubleshooting badly performing models

Tags: machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

Im creating my first predictive model and its results are absolutely awful.
Im in need of some help identifying how i troubleshoot this.

Im doing linear regression & logistic regression classification, to predict if a student will pass a course, 1 for yes, 0 for no.

The dataset is tiny, as we only have complete data for one class, 16 features just under 60 rows, 35 passed and 25 failed.
I'm wondering if my dataset is simply too small.

I dont want to share the dataset just yet, but will clean it up so its completely anonymous.

The ROC is very very jagged and mostly (for log regression), and predicts more false positives than anything else.

Id appreciate some general troubleshooting advice for a beginner that i can try before we hire in a professional.

Thanks for any help provided.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Id suggest some tips:

- In Azure ML theres a module called "filter based feature selection", you can use it to score your features and check if there is really predictive power in them or even select just the ones with the highest score.
- If you haven't ,splitt in train/cross validation set and evaluate your model in both and use it as a diagnosis to identify underfitting(high bias) or overfitting(high variance), and depending on the diagnosis perform actions like:
- For overfitting: get more data, use less features, use a less complex model , add or increase regularization
- For underfitting: add more features, use a more complex model, decrease regularization.

And don't forget ,before start training to explore and evaluate your data, use scatter plots to see if indeed its separable, perform feature engineering and preprocessing for this ask yourself: given this features, would a human expert be able to perform predictions?, if your answer is not, transform or drop features so that the answer is positive

Comment: Thanks Luis. Il spend a few days on feature generation to see if I can make anything out of the data.  Is it common that there simply is not enough of a relationship between the data to make an accurate prediction and rather than torture the data to do something it just can't do, it's better to call it quits on that particular set of features and data?

Comment: Yep, it may be the case that the dataset its not highly correlated , or maybe that its too small dataset ,thats whay exploration, and feature engineering and preprocessing its important ,the filter based feature selection in azure its excelent to help you on that pre-training tasks ,maybe the dataset as is is not that powerful but after some cleaning, adding some calculated features, removing others ,it will be a different story